# Sign up with more features

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress 
Can i make a plugin that add more action to a registration form? 
Like

- adding an action that hit an api after submitting a registration
- or redirecting to another site

Thank

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to do this? This isn't a coding or tutoring service, you are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Yeah
I am already tried it 
Since it's my first time asking for help here
And it's my first writing plugin in wordpress 
I am having no clue to how to start 
Sorry if that wrong

Comment: This isn't a tutoring service, we are not here to show you how to write a plugin - you need to **do your own research** to find out how and make a good attempt at writing it yourself. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and your relevant code - none of which is in your question. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @FluffyKitten ty for your advice
I am kinda clueless because it's my first time posting question here

Comment: If you are unsure of how to use the site, you can review [the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for more information.

Comment: @FluffyKitten ty
Will do better next time

Comment: The better the question and the more helpful information you can give, the more we can help :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten okay
Sorry to bother you
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add action after regitrastion

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'gandhy_function', 10, 1 );

function gandhy_function( $user_id ) {

    // YOUR action
wp_redirect( $url );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
And is there a way i can retrieve user input from those registration form like a class or something?

Comment: This is not how to write a plugin, this just hooks into an action. Also, its against Stack Overflow guidelines to answer low-quality questions, see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "*Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem*". Answering low-quality questions just encourages more poor quality questions. Save your well-intentioned efforts for questions that show some effort on the part of the person asking.